# Weblogic 12c: How to rotate servername.out file

Tags: weblogic12c, log-rotation

How to configure rotation for servername.out files? We have a configuration in admin console to rotate servername.log file, but there is no configuration to rotate the servername.out files.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any option in Weblogic to rotate the `stdout` file by default. What you may be able to do is force the `stdout` values into the regular logfile for which you can setup rotation strategies. Add the following to your startup parameters

```
-Dweblogic.log.RedirectStdoutToServerLogEnabled=true
```

Documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24428/config_logs.htm#WLLOG163).

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the solution. The Logging configuration in weblogic admin console controls both the log & out files. So the logging can be controlled by the settings available in admin control under `Environment-Servers-<Server>-Logging-General`

Answer (score 0):

By default the .out file is not having an rotation (based on time/size) as the .log files

We can implement a linux utility called logrotate and configure the .out file location. by this way we can do the rotation of .out file based on size.

Providing an stdout path at server start argument will only rotate the .out log when the jvm (managed server) is restarted.

more info on logrotate is [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-logfiles-with-logrotate-on-ubuntu-16-04)